# How to type subscript and superscript in resources.resx file?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have to set the setting in this file with subscript and superscript.
But i don't now how to type them.

More detail.
I have to fill the chemical elements such as h2o, but i don't know how to type it in the resources.resx file with "2" to be subscript.

Please help.

Comment: Plain text (which is what strings in RESX files are) does not have concept of sub/super script. Explaining more context for the problem would make it possible to suggest approaches to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings in resource files are plain text (no formatting), but can contain any Unicode character. So you could use Unicode subscripts and superscripts.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts):

> Unicode has subscripted and superscripted versions of a number of characters including a full set of arabic numerals. These characters allow any polynomial, chemical and certain other equations to be represented in plain text without using any form of markup like HTML or TeX.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Consolidated for cut-and-pasting purposes, the Unicode standard defines complete sub- and super-scripts for numbers and common mathematical symbols ( ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ ⁺ ⁻ ⁼ ⁽ ⁾ ₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉ ₊ ₋ ₌ ₍ ₎ ), a full superscript Latin lowercase alphabet except q ( ᵃ ᵇ ᶜ ᵈ ᵉ ᶠ ᵍ ʰ ⁱ ʲ ᵏ ˡ ᵐ ⁿ ᵒ ᵖ ʳ ˢ ᵗ ᵘ ᵛ ʷ ˣ ʸ ᶻ ), a limited uppercase Latin alphabet ( ᴬ ᴮ ᴰ ᴱ ᴳ ᴴ ᴵ ᴶ ᴷ ᴸ ᴹ ᴺ ᴼ ᴾ ᴿ ᵀ ᵁ ⱽ ᵂ ), a few subscripted lowercase letters ( ₐ ₑ ₕ ᵢ ⱼ ₖ ₗ ₘ ₙ ₒ ₚ ᵣ ₛ ₜ ᵤ ᵥ ₓ ), and some Greek letters ( ᵅ ᵝ ᵞ ᵟ ᵋ ᶿ ᶥ ᶲ ᵠ ᵡ ᵦ ᵧ ᵨ ᵩ ᵪ ). Note that since these glyphs come from different ranges, they may not be of the same size and position, depending on the typeface.

*Examples:*  H₂O, C₈H₁₀N₄O₂

Answer (score 1):

If you are rending your output to a web page then you can embed the HTML mark-up <sub> <sub>subscript text</sub></sub> and <sup><sup>superscript text</sup></sup> into the text directly.

if you are using some other display then you need to parse the text that you return and process the mark-up yourself.